# Characterization of positive-definite kernels via Fourier transforms of measures

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-transform, positive-definite

A function $x\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow f(x)\in\mathbb{C}$ is said to be positive semidefinite if, for every integer $n$ and any collection $\{x_j\}_{j=1,\dots,n}\subset\mathbb{R}$, the matrix $\left(f(x_j-x_k)\right)_{j,k}$ is positive semidefinite; that is, if the inequality
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j,k=1}^n z_j\overline{z_k}f(x_j-x_k)\geq0
\end{equation}
holds for every $\{x_j\}_{j=1,\dots,n}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\{z_j\}_{j=1,\dots,n}\subset\mathbb{C}$. By Bochner's theorem, continuous positive semidefinite functions can be uniquely reconstructed as the Fourier transform of a finite real measure $\mu$:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\int e^{-isx}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s).
\end{equation}
Now, more generally consider a two-variable function (kernel) $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto F(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}$. Similarly as above, the kernel is said to be positive semidefinite if, for every integer $n$ and any collection $\{x_j\}_{j=1,\dots,n}\subset\mathbb{R}$, the matrix $\left(F(x_j,x_k)\right)_{j,k}$ is positive semidefinite, that is,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j,k=1}^n z_j\overline{z_k}F(x_j,x_k)\geq0
\end{equation}
for every choice of the parameters.

Clearly, translation-invariant positive semidefinite kernels ($F(x+w,y+w)=F(x,y)$) are (uniquely identifiable with) positive semidefinite functions. In this regard, it would be natural to expect a generalization of Bochner's theorem to positive semidefinite kernels, my guess being the following: there exists a finite real measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
\begin{equation}
F(x,y)=\iint e^{-i(sx+s'y)}\mathrm{d}\mu(s,s').
\end{equation}
Indeed, it is easy to show that such functions are always positive semidefinite; the case of a translation-invariant kernel would be recovered by assuming $\mu$ to be supported on the line $s'=-s$.

However, I was not able to find any such characterization for positive semidefinite kernels. Is there any counterexample? Or, is this characterization actually true? I am aware of the link between such kernels and reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces, but it is not obvious to me how to reconstruct such an integral expression from them.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to my question can be found in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-integral-equations-and-applications/volume-16/issue-1/Positive-Definiteness-Integral-Equations-and-Fourier-Transforms/10.1216/jiea/1181075257.full) by J. Buescu, A.C. Paixao, F. Garcia, and I. Lourtie. They address the particular case of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ kernels, that is,
\begin{equation}
\iint|F(x,y)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y<\infty,
\end{equation}
whence their Fourier transform $\hat{F}(s,t)$ is well-defined and $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ as well. Then it is easy to show that $F(x,y)$ is positive definite if and only if $\hat{F}(s,-t)$ is; that is, $F(x,y)$ is positive definite if and only if it can be written as
\begin{equation}
F(x,y)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\iint e^{-\mathrm{i}(sx-ty)}\hat{F}(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}
Importantly, while being a positive semidefinite kernel, $\hat{F}(s,t)$ *is not positive-valued*; $F(x,y)$ can indeed be written as the Fourier-Stieltjes transform (up to a sign) of the *complex-valued* absolutely continuous measure $\hat{F}(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t$, whose density defines a positive semidefinite kernel.

In the general case, relaxing the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$-finiteness assumption, I'm still not aware of analogous results; I would expect something similar with non-absolutely continuous measures, but at the moment that is just a guess.